# Maximum storage amount for document that has embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I understand that in MongoDB a BSON document can be no bigger than 16mb. Does this size limit account for embedded documents as well? I plan on having well over 16mb of documents inside the embedding document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single MongoDB document cannot be larger than 16 MB and all of a document's embedded documents count toward this limit, so what you're planning won't work.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I'll have to look into GridFS.